# Computer power supply issues

Tags: power-supply, computer-building

I am trying to fix a friends computer. He said there was an issue with this powersupply:

```
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817170017&cm_re=logisys-_-17-170-017-_-Product
```

I bought a replacement from newegg (Same exact powersupply). After installing it and plugging it in I fired up the machine. As soon as it turned on the HDD smoked a bit. I assume its fried and im out a hard drive. I went over to eggxpert.com (a newegg user help community) and asked what could be the issue and they said the new powersupply is just a piece of crap. Is this the only conclusion that can be made? Could the powersupply just be that awful that it breaks computer components on arrival or could it be some error of mine with plugging things. This is my first try at diying a computer repair. thanks

Comment: What was the issue with his power supply? Have you double checked your work? Because you should be careful when doing your first computer repair in someone else his computer. We can't really help you other than to say "it's broken now", you could test the voltages of the power supply if you look up how to do that to confirm that it's not the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible causes:

- Power supply voltage switch was set at 240 instead of 120.
- Power supply or something got wet somehow
- You plugged in something the wrong way somehow (difficult but possible)
- You plugged in something in the wrong socket (difficult but possible)
- Screws or other metal items are on the motherboard, shorting it
- Pin bent on socket when you removed or plugged in things, causing 2 pins to go into 1 hole in the socket, or missing
- Is the floppy connector possibly connected to a fan connector on the motherboard?

I wouldn't put it past a faulty power supply to cause this but it's more likely something you did.

Comment: Molex connectors are keyed to prevent insertion the wrong way (which would connect +12v where +5v is expected, possibly resulting in failure), but I've seen people push hard enough to overcome the keying before. Make sure you always take a look at the connector and the socket to visually make sure the alignment keys/corners/notches match.

Answer (score 0):

A new power supply should most likely work, I guess there is something else wrong.

It's time to divide and conquer individual components, to [shape your problems into solutions](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/07/solving-problems/).